# I'm created desktop app by visual studio community version, but I found some application online can decompile my app and view my code

Tags: visual-studio

I'm created desktop app by visual studio community version,
but I found some application online can decompile my app and view my code!
what is the problem here?

Comment: some languages compile to an intermediate language that is easy to decompile, solution use a different language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple programs available that can decompile the application code. You have to implement some measures to protect the app from decompiling.

The process of protecting the executables of the app from getting decompiled into the original source code is called Obfuscation.
There are lots of applications available to Obfuscate the application. Some apps are free and included with Visual Studio.

One of the best utility for obfuscating is ConfuserEx and it's completely free and open-source.